# Android parsing and formatting DateTime timestamp

Tags: java, android, datetime

I need help with Android / Java text formatting. I've been wrestling with how to parse and format a Google DateTime string from SQLite data base. There error i get is

```
E/TAG﹕ Parsing ISO8601 datetime failed
    java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-08-04T18:20:00.000-04:00" (at offset 10)
            at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:579)
```

The method i've written is

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.TimeZone;
```

...

```
public String formatDueDate(String queryResponse) {
        DateFormat iso8601Format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        try {
             date = iso8601Format.parse(queryResponse);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Parsing ISO8601 datetime failed", e);
        }

        long when = date.getTime();
        int flags = 0;
        flags |= android.text.format.DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME;
        flags |= android.text.format.DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE;
        flags |= android.text.format.DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_MONTH;
        flags |= android.text.format.DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR;

       return android.text.format.DateUtils.formatDateTime(mContext,
                when + TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(when), flags);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try change from

```
DateFormat iso8601Format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

to

```
DateFormat iso8601Format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

Comment: My code seems to give a timestamp that is four hours behind the device timezone. Any tips to adjust `formatDateTime(mContext,
                when + TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(when), flags);` ?